# How can I verify the relation $m\omega^2 = |\textrm{constant}|$ using logarithmic plot?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, scales

We have demonstrated the uniform circular motion in the lab. Centripetal force and the radius are constant while the mass of the object increased 5 times thus 5 different angular velocities were measured. What the teacher wants from us is to verify this relation using a logarithmic plot on MatLab. I've been searching online for at least 8 hours now, but couldn't come up with a solution.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The trick of using different plot styles to demonstrate the form of equations is still useful for *exhibiting* the form of the data, but ... using a program with a powerful fitter to replicate the old pencil-and-paper scheme for analysis is strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the constant $E$, then you have $\omega^2=\frac{E}{m}$, or $\log(\omega)=\frac{1}{2}\log(E)-\frac12\log(m)$. If you plot $\omega$ as a function of $m$ on a loglog plot you should get a straight line of slope $-\frac12$ and $y$ intercept $\frac12\log(E)$.

Comment: When I plot the graph on Matlab using plot(log(x), log(y)) the slope is -1/2but the constant is 0.73 while my constant is "4.3". And if I use loglog(x,y), then the slope is 24 when I apply linear fitting.

Comment: well, this is really a Matlab question, but I'm guessing you're using the inbuilt fitting tool of the plot. That (I think) tries to fit your actual datapoints: loglog(x,y) plots (x,y) and then changes the scales, so when you try to fit the tool tries to fit y(x) as if it was a linear function, but it's not, so of course you're going to get an absurd result. Instead use [polyfit](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) with log(x) and log(y) and then plot the fitted line the loglog plot with the datapoints

Comment: also the $y$ intercept, call it $y_0$, is $\frac12 \log E$, so $E=e^{2y_0}$ and surprise $e^{2\cdot 0.73}=4.3$

Comment: I've been searching for the past 15 hours now and apparently all I needed was to learn that the log function on MatLab has a base of e, not 10.

Comment: @Ç.Eti hehe, in my experience, when they write $\log$, most mathematicians and physicists mean base $e$ and most computer scientists mean base $2$. Only in high school it's taken to be base $10$ as far as I know, maybe in engineering? I don't know. Either way Matlab has the function `log10` if you ever need it